Changing java jdk on springboot maven project
I was using java jdk 17 before and i built all my springboots maven projects with jdk 17 but now i have installed java jdk 23 on my laptop and then i tried running my springboot maven projects and it is telling me error
So, i tried changing the version from 17 to 23 and also changing it in my project structure in intellij but still getting thesame error of
Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\SpringBoot Projects\springboot-jwt-token-auth\springboot-jwt-token-auth\target\classes\com\abdul\springbootjwttokenauth\config\JwtAuthenticationFilter.class]

and
Unsupported class file major version 67


The version of Spring (Boot) in use doesn't support Java 23 as quite apparent by the messages you get.

Check if you've pointed the environment variables JAVA_HOME to Java 23

My suspicion is that you've updated everything correctly except for your runtime.  In other words, from the error message, it appears that you have built with Java 23 (major version 67) but are running it with a lower version of the JRE.

Update the Java Version in Maven Configuration:
<properties>
    <java.version>23</java.version>
</properties>

Invalidate Caches and Restart IntelliJ: In IntelliJ, go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart.
Delete Target Directory: 

mvn clean install

Check for Compatibility with JDK 23:  You may need to update Spring Boot or specific dependencies to ensure compatibility with JDK 23.
Verify JDK in IntelliJ: Go to File > Project Structure > Project and make sure the Project SDK is set to JDK 23. Also, check Modules > Sources to confirm the Language level is compatible with your JDK 23
https://admirable-smakager-729141.netlify.app/post/2
